# change div containing checkbox attributes when checked

Tags: php, javascript, html

this is my javascript that allows for a filter search field ...

```
function escape4regex(text)
{
  return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
}

function searchRegExFieldKeyUp()
{
    var table = document.getElementById('ModelFilter');
    var cells = table.getElementsByTagName('div');
    var searchterms = escape4regex(this.value);

    var regVar = '(?=.*' + searchterms.replace(/\s/g, '.*)(?=.*') + '.*)';
    var i=cells.length;
    while (i--)
    {
       var cell = cells[i];

       var rowStr = cell.innerHTML;
       // remove all tags
      rowStr = rowStr.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '').replace(/\n|\s{2,}/gm, ' '); // searches  whole row 

      var regex = new RegExp(regVar,"gi");
      var result = (regex.test(rowStr));

     if(result)
     {
        cell.style.display = "";// check if compat with IE
     }
     else
     {
       cell.style.display = "none";
     }
   }
}
```

this creates checkboxes from databse inputs

```
<div id="ModelFilter">
<?php 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo"<div class=\"modelfilter_td\" id=\"modelfilter_td\">";
        echo"<input type=\"checkbox\" id = \"$row[ModelID]\" 
            name = \"selectedModels[]\"value =\"$row[Model]\" onclick=\"chkcontrol.apply(this);\">";
        echo "$row[Model]";
    echo"</div>";
}
echo"</div>";
```

I want to do the following :

1. when the checkbox is checked, it stays visible, even if it is not in the search terms of the filter field.
2. when the checkbox is checked , the background color is changed.
3. the checkbox and the title for the checkbox is held within a div, I want to allow the user to click anywhere in the  div to allow toggling of the checkbox.

Anyone start  me ont the right track with this?

EDIT: here is a solution to problem "3."

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".modelfilter_td").click(function(e){
    var chk = $($(this).find("input[type='checkbox']"));
    if(chk.attr('checked'))
    {
        chk.attr('checked',false);
    }else{
        chk.attr('checked',true);
    }

   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution for you problem, but a recommendation on php-usage in html context:

```
<div id="ModelFilter">
    <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
    <div class="modelfilter_td" id="modelfilter_td">
        <input  
            type="checkbox"
            id="<?php echo $row['ModelID'] ?>" 
            name="selectedModels[]"
            value="<?php echo $row['Model'] ?>"
            onclick="chkcontrol.apply(this);"
        >
        <?php echo $row['Model'] ?>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile ?>
</div>
```

This enables most IDEs to deal with HTML-autocompletion and code-analysis.

Comment: im getting an unexpected $end on the endwhile ?

Comment: In an isolated environment, this code is valid. Have you 1:1 copied the code? If not, have you noticed the double colon at the end of the while()-statement?
If yes: Is the  context correct? This code wont run in PHP-context /(Think of <?php <?php ?> ?>).